# How to install wine on Ubuntu 16.04 x64

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, wine

I've downloaded wine-1.8.4.tar.bz2 and can't install it. After  `sudo ./configure  --enable-win64` there's a message:

```
checking for X... no
configure: error: X 64-bit development files not found. Wine will be built
without X support, which probably isn't what you want. You will need
to install 64-bit development packages of Xlib/Xfree86 at the very least.
Use the --without-x option if you really want this.
```

1. Even if I solved this, would there be other problems?
2. How can I install wine on my Ubuntu amd64?
3. Can you tell me all the steps to do it?

Comment: WINE is available in the official repositories. Using the software center or just *sudo apt install wine* should be enough. Any special reason why you're downloading it?

Comment: yeah,  I don't have Internet traffic enough to do  that.

Comment: Really? But you had enough to download an even bigger package? OK...

Comment: no, my friend downloaded it and it was just 22 mb. is it problem to just help?

Comment: Please read the part about "Installing without Internet": https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu

Comment: you know, I really need lots of .exe programs. So it is impossible installing off-line, isn't it?

Comment: If you need lots a Windows software - you certainly don't but to each its own - then perhaps you should seriously consider using Windows in dual-boot or instead of Ubuntu. Ubuntu is NOT a free replacement for Windows.

Comment: yeah I know that. however I need.

Answer (score 1):

## Wine offline installation (amd64)

I've created a script containing all dependency download links for wine. You can download all the files and put them in a folder, cd to it and run the command `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` then you should be able to completely install wine without internet connection. I assume you are using 64-bit system so there is an amd64 wine version. https://ghostbin.com/paste/4swqm

Comment: Thanks) by the way, isn't it 1.8.4 version?

Comment: it's the latest stable version available on repository. If you see my answer is useful, please accept it @Steve

Comment: can I run any Windows programs via that version? I mean even the latest programs

Comment: To satisfy your wish, you should install a virtual machine ;)